# How to update args to Sidekiq cron job after initialize in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I am using sidekiq gem for process the background job and sidekiq-cron job to schedule the job at given time period.

```
#config/schedule.yml

my_first_job:
  cron: "*/5 * * * *"
  class: "HardWorker"
  queue: hard_worker
```

I want to pass date (dynamic) as argument to the worker in schedule.yml.

Loading `config/schedule.yml`

```
#initializers/sidekiq.rb
schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"

if File.exist?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
end

job = Sidekiq::Cron::Job.find("my_first_job")
job.args = [Date.yesterday, Date.today]
```

When I find `Sidekiq::Cron::Job.find("my_first_job")`, I see job is updated with date args. But I don't see the date at `http://localhost:3000/sidekiq/cron` after I restart Sidekiq.

How to update args in Sidekiq cron job after loaded? `Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)`